# Positive infinity or unsigned infinity?? Limits - $\lim_{x\to4}\frac{x}{x-4}$

Tags: limits

I have to evaluate the limit below(Without graphing),

$$\lim_{x\to4}\frac{x}{x-4}$$

Okay, I substituted the value, 4.

$$\frac{4}{4-4}$$

So I got,

$$\frac{4}{0}$$

Now, would this be positive ininity or just infinity??

I would like to know why

Or,did I do something wrong while solving?

Comment: Have you drawn a sketch graph to see what is going on?

Comment: Note: sometimes a graph helps you to see what you need to do to find a proof "without a graph" - if you have a function you don't quite understand, a sketch is a handy tool, even if it is erased when you find the answer you need.

Comment: Perhaps substitute in $u=x-4$. We now have: $\lim_{u\to0}\frac{u-4}u=\lim_{u\to0}(1-4\frac1u)$. We know that $\lim_{u\to0}\frac1u$ is unsigned infinity, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$\lim_{x \to 4^+} \dfrac{x}{x-4} = +\infty \text{ and }\lim_{x \to 4^-} \dfrac{x}{x-4} = -\infty$$

---

A more formal argument is as follows:

Given any $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$, for all $x > \dfrac{4}{1-1/M}$, we have $$\dfrac{x}{x-4} > M$$ Hence, $\lim_{x \to 4^+} \dfrac{x}{x-4} = +\infty$. Similarly, argue for $x \to 4^-$.

---

The graph of $\dfrac{x}{x-4} $near $4$ looks as shown below

[image]

Comment: Can we do this without graphing?

Comment: @Adhvaitha Can I ask, in which program you made this graph?

Comment: Yes this can be done without graphing. Consider limits from the left and limits from the right. You will get $+\infty$ from one and $-\infty$ from the other.

Comment: @didgocks The graph is not needed as shown in the first statement. As $x \to 4^+$, note that both the numerator and denominator are positive. Similarly, argue for $x \to 4^-$.

Comment: @Tacet Grapher on Max OS X. Wonderful tool.

Comment: @Adhvaitha Och, unfortunately I doesn't have OS X. Thanks anyway. I'm going to find something on Penguin.

Comment: @Tacet There's [desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com), a nice online grapher.

Comment: @Tacet If you want a crossplatform graphing tool, look into gnuplot, it's the best there is. It is a bit difficult to learn though. Here's an [example plot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hDdzN.png)

Comment: @Tacet There is [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), another beautiful open source software.

Comment: Hakim, Adhvaitha: I know, but I prefer local sources. However, thank you for the link. @KristofferRyhl Thx for the name. I'll check it. Ok. I end up with chatting in the comments. ;)

Comment: @Tacet Mathematica always works if you want the nuclear solution to any problem :P

Answer (score 2):

$$ 
\lim_{x\to4}\frac{x}{x-4} =\mbox{does not exist} 
$$
Because 
$$ \lim_{x\to4^-}\frac{x}{x-4} =-\infty $$
And
$$ \lim_{x\to4^+}\frac{x}{x-4} =\infty $$

Answer (score 1):

Some teachers distinguish between signed and unsigned infinity. I think this is a perversion, because saying that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1}{x}=\infty \text{ (unsigned)}
$$
doesn't give the same amount of information as saying
$$
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty
$$

The definition of limit “unsigned infinity” is given as

> for all $M>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that, for $0<|x-a|<\delta$, $|f(x)|>M$

and written $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=\infty$. Note that it just amounts to saying that
$$
\lim_{x\to a}|f(x)|=+\infty
$$
but also that this definition is nonsense: consider
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
1/x & \text{for $x$ irrational}\\
-1/x & \text{for $x\ne0$ rational}
\end{cases}
$$
and prove that $\lim_{x\to0}f(x)=\infty$ (unsigned).

So, yes, you *could* say that $\lim_{x\to 4}x/(x-4)=\infty$ (unsigned) and maybe you *must* say it, if your instructor wants you to.

For the vast majority of mathematicians, this limit doesn't exist, because
$$
\lim_{x\to4^-}\frac{x}{x-4}=-\infty
\quad\text{and}\quad
\lim_{x\to4^+}\frac{x}{x-4}=+\infty
$$

Unsigned infinity can actually be given a meaning in the context of rational functions or, more generally, branches of algebraic curves, but it involves concepts from projective geometry and it is not as useful as distinguishing between infinite limits from the right and on the left with proper “signs”.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers suggesting using the graph or the notion of left/right hand limits are good and probably more intuitive at your stage. However, I will make note of another way of seeing this.

Just divide the numerator by the denominator using [polynomial] long division:
$$
\frac{x}{x-4}=1+\frac{4}{x-4}
$$
So that we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 4}\frac{x}{x-4}=\lim_{x\to 4} \bigg(1+\frac{4}{x-4}\bigg)
$$
But $\lim_{x \to 4} \frac{4}{x-4}$ clearly does not exist so that the original limit cannot exist.