# Is there a proof for $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{x-a} = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am an adult software developer who is trying to do a math reboot. I am working through the exercises in the following book.

Ayres, Frank , Jr. and Elliott Mendelson. 2013. *Schaum's Outlines Calculus Sixth Edition (1,105 fully solved problems, 30 problem-solving videos online)*. New York: McGraw Hill. ISBN 978-0-07-179553-1.

So far as I can tell, the following question either has a misprint or the book does not cover the material.  It is entirely possible that I failed to grasp a key important sentence.

**Chapter 7 Limits, problem 24.**

Use the precise definition to prove:

$$
\text{a)  }\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty \\
\text{b)  }\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} = \infty \\
$$

**My understanding.**

It is possible to prove $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = +\infty$ or $\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$, but not $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ because $\frac{1}{x}$ is a hyperbola with no limit at 0.  A similar argument can be made for $\frac{x}{x-1}$ at 1.

Is there a proof for $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{1}{x-a} = \infty$?

Comment: Your understanding is correct.

Comment: yes, and in general be careful with Schaum's outlines. I love them, but they are riddled with mistakes

Comment: Sometimes $\infty$ means unsigned infinity: $|\hbox{function}|$ is biggger and bigger near of the point. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045664/positive-infinity-or-unsigned-infinity-limits-lim-x-to4-fracxx-4.

Comment: What is your precise definition of limit?

Comment: I agree with @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: check the exact meaning of the symbol $\infty$ in the book.

Comment: Unsigned infinity is defined as such: as $x$ approaches $a$, $|f(x)|$ eventually becomes greater than any preassigned positive number.  Hence $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = +\infty$.

Comment: The precise definition of a limit is defined as such: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = +\infty$ if and only if, for any positive number $M$, there exists a positive number $\delta$ such that, whenever $0 < |x-a| < \delta$, then $f(x) > M$.  The definition for $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = -\infty$ is similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also in this case the limit doesn't exist but we can consider the two side limits

$$\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{1}{x-a} = +\infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to a^-} \frac{1}{x-a} = -\infty$$

for the proof a simple way is set $y=x-a\to 0$ and the limits become the simpler

$$\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{y} = +\infty$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{y} = -\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

No since the graph of $\frac1{x-a}$ is just that of $\frac1x$ shifted $a$ units horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

A function is not defined properly unless you specify its domain. When we say the function $\frac{1}{x}$ we usually mean the function $f: \mathbb{R}\setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ defined by $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace $. Here $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) $ does not eexist.

But when you take $g=f_{|[0, \infty)}$ then we can say that $\lim_{x \to a} g(x) = \infty$.

So try to find out the domain of the mapping from the context.

Comment: The book states the following in the previous chapter.  "In general, if a function is given by means of a formula, then, if nothing is said to the contrary, we shall assume that the domain consists of all numbers for which the formula is defined."  All real numbers are mentioned in the preceding sentence, in reference to a function example.