# Use the precise definition to prove $\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} = \infty$.

Tags: calculus, limits

This is a concrete follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2785912/is-there-a-proof-for-lim-x-to-a-frac1x-a-infty).

I am an adult software developer who is trying to do a math reboot. I am working through the exercises in the following book.

Ayres, Frank , Jr. and Elliott Mendelson. 2013. *Schaum's Outlines Calculus Sixth Edition (1,105 fully solved problems, 30 problem-solving videos online)*. New York: McGraw Hill. ISBN 978-0-07-179553-1.

The above book does not give an example of solving a question exactly like the following.

**Chapter 7 Limits, problem 24.**

Use the precise definition to prove:

$$
\text{b)  }\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} = \infty \\
$$

**Notes.**

Unsigned infinity is defined as such: as $x$ approaches $a$, $|f(x)|$ eventually becomes greater than any preassigned positive number. Hence $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = +\infty$.

The precise definition of a limit is defined as such: $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = +\infty$ if and only if, for any positive number $M$, there exists a positive number $\delta$ such that, whenever $0<|x−a|<\delta$, then $f(x)>M$. The definition for $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = −\infty$ is similar.

**My attempt.**

Does this work as a proof?  I am not convinced this is complete.

Let $0 < M$ be given.  Let $0 < \delta = \min\big(1, \frac{1}{|M-1|}\big)$. Suppose $x < 1$ and $0 < |x-1| < \delta$.  Then $|x-1| < \frac{1}{|M-1|} < 1$.  Hence $|M-1| < \frac{1}{|x-1|}$ or $M < \big|\frac{x}{x-1}\big|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x}{x-1} = +\infty \neq \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x}{x-1} = -\infty
$$

For the proof we can set $x-1=y\to 0$ and then

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{x}{x-1} =\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{y+1}{y} =\lim_{y \to 0} 1+\frac{1}{y}$$

and then reduce to prove that

$$\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1}{y}=\infty$$

Comment: The workbook handles $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \frac{x}{x-1} = +\infty \neq \lim_{x \to 1^-} \frac{x}{x-1} = -\infty
$ by saying that $\lim_{x \to a} |f(x)| = +\infty$.  Having said that, I am more interested in general techniques that the way the workbook does things.  Is setting $x-1=y\to 0$ generally preferable to futzing around with absolute values?

Comment: @sgeos By the change of variable we can reduce to prove a simpler case. Of course we can limit to the case $\lim_{y \to 0^+} \frac{1}{y}=+\infty$ or $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{1}{|y|}=+\infty$ and from here deduce that $\lim_{y \to 0^-} \frac{1}{y}=-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are going "backwards".  You say "let M> 0 be given" but end by giving a condition on M.  You want to show that, for any M, there exist $\delta$ such that if $|x- 1|<\delta$ then $\frac{x}{x- 1}> M$.

In order that $\frac{x}{x- 1}> M$, we must have **either** $x> M(x- 1)$ (if x> 1) or $x< M(x- 1)$ (if x< 1).

In the first case, x> 1, $x> Mx- M$ so $x- Mx= (1- M)x> -M$ and therefore $(M-1)x< M$. So $x< \frac{M}{M-1}$, and $x- 1= |x- 1|< \frac{M}{M-1}- 1=\frac{1}{M-1}$.  That is, we can take $\delta$ to be less than $\frac{1}{M- 1}$.

I will leave the case x< 1 to you.

Comment: My understanding is that that the last statement is the proof that no matter how large $M$ is, $\big|\frac{x}{x-1}\big|$ will always be larger.  Therefore $\lim_{x \to 1} \big|\frac{x}{x-1}\big| = +\infty$.  Having said that, I am terrible at writing proofs and it is entirely possible that I failed to explicit state something very important.  Is it just easier to explicitly brach on $x<1$ versus $1<x$ instead of futzing around with absolute values in the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Note:

$\dfrac{x-1+1}{x-1} = 1+\dfrac{1}{x-1}.$

1) Consider $ x \rightarrow 1^+:$

Choose $M$, real, positive, and

$\delta >0$ with $\delta < 1/M.$

Then  $|x-1|= x-1 \lt \delta$ implies

$M < 1+  1/\delta < 1+\dfrac{1}{x-1} .$

2) Remains to consider $x \rightarrow 1^-.$

Comment: Eliminating an $x$ from the numerator is a clever strategy.

Comment: Sgeos. Simpler this way.Greetings